# paramiko execute multiple commands with blocking

Tags: python, paramiko

I am using `client.exec_command` to run several commands consecutively but seems it's non-blocking. Sometimes I want to wait for a command to finish before running the next one. I know I can utilize a channel's API `chan.exec_command` and wait on it's exit status, which works but the channel closes after running the command and I have to start a new channel each time for the next command. What I'm looking for is some clean solution that run multiple commands consecutively and wait on each one, just like how a person doing it manually.

New to Python too. Any comment is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, this seems to be what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6203953/637754

Comment: thank you both for timely replying. I actually noticed that question, but didn't give the solution a try as it's still running client.exec_commands so I was guessing it would still be nonblocking. Any idea?